# HID joystick to function with modern games

Tags: c, usb, hid

I recently had success putting together a little homemade joystick with analog stick and four buttons that map to keystrokes.  It works fine with Windows - moves the cursors, buttons light up appropriately - but then I went to see if I could use it in a game (Fortnite) and the stick doesn't work.  The buttons function, but that's only because they are keystrokes.  Poking around, I see that Xbox and PS4 controllers - the ones that games like Fortnite allow - have all sorts of fancy, and I suppose closed, unique descriptors.

Is it possible to get a homemade HID controller to work with games that are looking for Xbox/PS4 controllers?  If so, is there a resource to help get started?

I'm still pretty new to USB and HIDs so I might be looking for the wrong things.

**EDIT**
I've been asked to include some extra information.  I'm using microcontrollers that support high speed, but full speed gives the same behavior. This happens on every microcontroller that I have available with a USB layer, in any language available including C, C++ and Python (I'm positive you'll see the same with Rust or anything else).  Here is a relatively minimal descriptor that exhibits this behavior - it is taken verbatim from the HID spec v1.11 except removing the hat switch usage since I don't have one (works the same if I leave it in and tie it to physical buttons):

```
Usage Page (Generic Desktop),
Usage (Joystick),
Collection (Application),
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop),
    Usage (Pointer),
    Collection (Physical),
        Logical Minimum (-127),
        Logical Maximum (127),
        Report Size (8),
        Report Count (2),
        Push,
        Usage (X),
        Usage (Y),
        Input (Data, Variable, Absolute),
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Count (2),
        Report Size (1),
        Usage Page (Buttons),
        Usage Minimum (Button 1),
        Usage Maximum (Button 2),
        Unit (None),
        Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    End Collection,
    Usage Minimum (Button 3),
    Usage Minimum (Button 4),
    Input (Data, Variable, Absolute),
    Pop,
    Usage (Throttle),
    Report Count (1),
    Input (Data, Variable, Absolute),
End Collection
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But it would be helpful if you could mention what kind of hardware and programming language you are using.

Comment: The unspecific question and missing information is probably the reason you didn't get an answer for your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646191/usb-hid-combination-device-appearance. Please improve this question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDikklGx-tM

Comment: @Codo could you help me out and let me know how this is non specific?  I'm just providing descriptors via microcontroller - in this case using any of a handful of STM32 micros or a PIC32.  Using any HID joystick example from any microcontroller with an analog stick instead of directional buttons will exhibit the same behavior. 
Not sure what else there is to know - do you want to see the descriptor?  It's almost the default HID joystick descriptor since i get the same behavior if the buttons function as generic buttons vs keystrokes, but I'm happy to provide it if that's the issue.

Comment: Maybe the game is ignoring traffic from devices with unrecognized vendor id/product ID (VID/PID). I would capture a Wireshark trace of a successful session and compare it to that of your home made device, then make adjustments to your descriptors as needed.

Comment: Does the joystick appear as a game controller (in Windows Settings)? Can you move the x and y axis in the game controller settings? And it might be helpful if you added the USB descriptor as well.

Comment: @Codo Yes, everything shows up like you would expect.  Windows installs everything correctly, I see the appropriate metadata from iManufacturer and iProduct and can see everything working well in the device properties and calibration windows.  The cursor moves fine, the x and y-axis values are as expected.  I'll add the USB descriptors when I get back to that computer.

Comment: @aja That is what I figured, I just sort of assumed that someone else would have encountered the same behavior and know if there's a way around it.  Specifically, Fortnite (I'm using that as a test case, I don't actually play the game) looks in configuration like it supports third-party controllers, but I don't think it does.  I don't have any other controllers to test - this is more of an academic question.  I am just interested if I should even bother trying to get this breadboard controller to work, or if it's simply impossible since I'm not MS or Sony.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that while your HID gamepad is recognized by windows (and so shows up in the "Set up USB game controllers" screen), most modern games on PC are looking for XInput devices. Long story short, I ran into this myself when I recently tried to put together a DIY fightstick for PC use.

While I don't know much about the particulars of how XInput devices actually work (it seems to be similar to a HID gamepad but with different descriptors etc), there exists an Arduino library called [ArduinoXInput](https://github.com/dmadison/ArduinoXInput) which can do the heavy lifting for you. This requires you to use one of the [supported board types](https://github.com/dmadison/ArduinoXInput#compatible-boards) and install the board core for said board. For example, I'm using an Arduino Pro Micro, and I installed the [XInput AVR core](https://github.com/dmadison/ArduinoXInput_AVR) which supports Arduino Leonardos.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).